# how to define Bean to `RestTemplate`?

Tags: micronaut

I am trying to use `RestTemplate` from `Spring-client`.

I cannot use `RestTemplate` because this class hasnot `bean`.

```
 public BusinessBankingTemplate(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }
```

i tried to find some documentation, for example from this
https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#factories

but i still have no idea how to implement it on Java language

This is my error log.

```
Message: No bean of type [org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate] exists. Ensure the class is declared a bean and if you are using Java or Kotlin make sure you have enabled annotation processing.
Path Taken: new TransactionCheckerJob(BcaService bcaService,Oauth2Template oauth2Template,[BusinessBankingTemplate businessBankingTemplate]) --> new BusinessBankingTemplate([RestTemplate restTemplate])
        at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanDefinition.getBeanForConstructorArgument(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:981)
        at bank.transaction.service.impl.$BusinessBankingTemplateDefinition.build(Unknown Source)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1331)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createAndRegisterSingleton(DefaultBeanContext.java:1914)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanForDefinition(DefaultBeanContext.java:1635)
```

Comment: Can you please copy/paste the actual error message you are getting?

Comment: @Matt please see my updated  post

Comment: Ok, it looks like you are trying to use Spring's autowiring to pass in the rest template object, but you're going to need to share some more code here. Where exactly are you creating your RestTemplate?

Comment: "Ok, it looks like you are trying to use Spring's autowiring to pass in the rest template object" - Why do you say that?

Comment: It looks to me like Micronaut's DI container is attempting doing the injection but no `RestTemplate` bean has been registered.  I don't see any evidence of Spring doing any autowiring here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After try to find some documentation, i found from micronaut user's guide has a feature where to register other class to bean like this.

```
@Factory
public class RestTemplateFactory {

    @Bean
    @Singleton
    public RestTemplate v8Engine() {
      return new RestTemplate();
    }
}
```

this code run well :)